# calculate the values grouping by date

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, io

Here's what my data looks like,

```
        user_id article_id  send_time author_id topic_id type_id
    0   11460         66 2015-01-02     18587       72      22
    1    5475         66 2015-01-02     18587       72      22
    2    1205         66 2015-01-02     18587       72      22
    3   17040         66 2015-01-02     18587       72      22
    4   18940         66 2015-01-02     18587       72      22
```

I tried using this code, once with format option once without. Without that option I get an error

Code

```
 np.savetxt(r'C:/Users/AmitSingh/Desktop/Data/data_scientist_test/access_log/new_dataframe.txt',new_dataframe.values)
```

Error

```
 TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e')
```

With the format option

Code

```
np.savetxt(r'C:/Users/AmitSingh/Desktop/Data/data_scientist_test/access_log/new_dataframe.txt',new_dataframe.values,fmt='%d')
```

Error

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%d %d %d %d %d %d')
```

What else can I do? I need to write this in a txt file, since there are too many rows to write in a csv/excel file

Comment: I added a numpy tag as you're using a numpy command rather than pandas to save the data.   I don't know of any row limit for CSV, so not sure what you mean.  And anyway, why not use HDF or some other format supported by pandas?  Binary formats are generally better than text formats.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because of mixed types (including `object` references) in your DataFrame.

Easiest solution is to use [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method instead of `numpy.savetxt`:

```
new_dataframe.to_csv(r'C:/Users/AmitSingh/Desktop/Data/data_scientist_test/access_log/new_dataframe.txt')
```